# Exercises 3.3 from Think Python

Tags: python, function

**Problem:** 
Python provides a built-in function called **len** that returns the length of a string, so the value of len('allen') is 5.
Write a function named **right_justify** that takes a string named **s** as a parameter and prints the string with enough leading spaces so that the last letter of the string is in column 70 of the display.

```
>>> right_justify('allen')
                                                                allen
```

I tried writing some codes as follows:

```
>>> def right_justify(s):
...     print                                                   s
...     
>>> right_justify('allen')
>>> allen
```

The result is without enough leading spaces required by the exercise. And I couldn't use the built-in function **len** to help solve it either.

Any idea on how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Given that the purpose of the exercise is for you to learn by trying different things, what kind of help do you want exactly? Being given the answer isn't going to help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it simply like this:

In Python 3.x :

```
print(" "*(70 - len(s)) + s)
```

And like this in Python 2.x :

```
print " "*(70 - len(s)) + s
```

Comment: Press the high button if it work for you. You just give me a bad score for my answer. Thanks

Comment: It's not me. Now I don't have enough reputation to vote up or down.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding *N - len(s)* spaces between `print` and `s` is not gonna help, as Python will simply ignore them. You can achieve this using string formatting:

```
>>> '{: >70}'.format('allen')
'                                                                 allen'
```

or `rjust` method of `str` objects:

```
>>> 'allen'.rjust(70)
'                                                                 allen'
```

or `format` function (which is the same as `str.format`, really):

```
>>> format('allen', ' >70')
'                                                                 allen'
```

Although the most straightforward way is

```
>>> s = 'allen'
>>> ' ' * (70 - len(s)) + s
'                                                                 allen'
```

Answer (score 1):

Whitespace inserted after the `print` will be ignored unless it is inside quotation marks (`'` or `"`). You can use `*` to insert a particular character lots of times, e.g. to insert 30 spaces you can write `' ' * 30`. So use this to insert the desired number of spaces which you know will be determined by `len(s)` and the chosen screen width of 70 columns.

Answer (score 0):

What your are doing is:

```
print (                                                        s)
```

The param "s" is the same. You can use the *just methods of the String class or something else. 
More info in [here](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/string-methods.html)